# LTSpice constraints on plots

Tags: simulation, ltspice, constraints

A have a circuit for which I have parameterized some of its resistors with the .STEP command. Consequently, I have many different graphs when I simulate the circuit. I would like to know if it was possible to put a constraint on the graphs that would tell the simulation which one can be plotted (like for example : V(vout) <= 100mV)?

Comment: I don't believe there is. And what's more annoying is that there's no way to really know which plot corresponds to each element in the .STEP command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to differentiate the steps in LTspice by Right-Clicking on the waveform's label (in the waveform window) and then adding `@x` to the trace's expression, where `x` is the step's number. For example, for `.step param x 1 5 2`, plotting `V(out)@1` will plot `V(out)` for the value `x=1` (first step), `V(out)@1` => `x=3` (2nd step), and `V(out)@3` => `x=5` (3rd step).

Alternately, you can Righ-Click in the waveform window and then on `Select steps`, where you will be presented a more graphical option of plotting the steps.

Note that you can't stop LTspice plotting all the steps when clicking on the node, but after you select the desired trace, it will stay plotted until overridden.

As a side note, in case you have stepped points and you have used `.MEAS` commands, the log file will have results for each step. With the log file still opened, you have theoption to plot the results with Righ-Click, then choose `Plot .step'ed .meas data`.